# How can i get Keyframes value in jquery

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

i have a progress bar and i want to get its value . .bar class inside css animates my progress bar and i wanted to get value of progress bar when keyframes value is on 0% 25% .. 100% in jquery.

```
     .bar 
    { border-radius:5px; 
       animation:myfirst 50s;
      -webkit-animation:myfirst 50s;
      -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
       animation-play-state:running; 
     } 
      @keyframes myfirst {
       0% { height:0%; } 
       25% { height:25%; } 
        50% { height:50%; }
       100% { height:100%; } 
       }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it this way since css animation doesn't trigger events.

Comment: Then how design a progress bar which should show value also

Comment: A progress bar that shows actual values would be driven by something that is happening.  What you have here is a pretend progress bar that goes from 0 to 100% in a given time.

Comment: Since my progress bar starts, when the page is loaded so can i make something like stop watch in jquery to show progress bar value.if yes then how can i make it?

Comment: But what progress are you showing?  Progress of what?

Comment: Its a game which will end when progress bar ends, and based on time left in progress bar it will be added to Total points.

Comment: You should do that with Date objects - create one at the start, one at the end and work out the difference in between them.  You don't create a progress bar and then get the value from it.  Progress bars are there to represent values.

Comment: Thanks Archer Date object was perfect for this secenario